# The function is javascript doesn't display the last element of array even though I am using pop()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to teach myself JS and I have tried this function and for some reason is it delivering me the first element of the array and not last.

Can someone please explain the reason of it, how can I fix it?

Thanks,

```js
const toDoList = ["sweeping", "washing", "mopping"];

function cleanUp() {
  for (let i = 0; i < toDoList.length; i++) {
    toDoList.pop(toDoList[i]);
  }
  console.log("I still have some " + toDoList + " to do");
}
cleanUp();
```

Comment: The `pop()` method doesn't take an argument.

Comment: [`.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) always removes the last element

Comment: You shouldn't delete from an array while you're iterating over it.

Comment: `array.unshift()` will remove the first element.

Comment: @MisterJojo take it easy, some beginners don't have the same "goto docs" instruction embedded in their behavior yet.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica Yet it is the first thing to know in any learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. `pop` doesn't take any parameters
2. you should never modify the size of an array (any method that changes the `length`) while looping over it with a `for` loop which depends on `length`.
3. you don't actually need a for loop, a `while` will do as well:

```js
const toDoList = ["sweeping", "washing", "mopping"];

function cleanUp() {
  while(toDoList.length) {
    const element = toDoList.pop();
    // do something with the element otherwise the loop is not needed
  }
  console.log("I still have some " + toDoList + " to do");
}
cleanUp();
```